# CardView flip animation

Tags: android, animation, android-cardview, android-viewflipper

I have seen examples of 'card flip animations' where the entire layout of an activity is changed using the animation, much like the [developer docs here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/animation/cardflip.html).

Is there a way I can have a similar kind of animation but only on one view?

Specifically, I have a `ViewFlipper` which contains two `CardView`s. When I flip the views, I would like there to be a flipping animation.

Currently I have sliding animations, but here is what I have so far:

```
private void showPrevious() {
    // If there aren't any other children, stop.
    if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Next screen comes in from left.
    mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
    // Current screen goes out from right.
    mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);

    // Display next screen.
    mViewFlipper.showNext();
}

private void showNext() {
    // If there is a child (to the left), stop.
    if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Next screen comes in from right.
    mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
    // Current screen goes out from left.
    mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);

    // Display previous screen.
    mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
}
```

Could the slide animations I have be replaced with a flip animation (where it appears as though the CardView is rotated in 3D)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made an Android library that contains a collection of useful widgets - it's called [**UsefulViews**](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews).

One of these widgets is the [`FlippableView`](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/satsuware/usefulviews/FlippableView.java).

You can have a look at the Javadoc to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to use your View but nothing is showing. I have set both front and back but they are not really rendering anything. Any idea why?